# use eval to evaluate a javascript snippet in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, textarea, eval, execute

I'm at my first hackathon and trying to finish my project. I am very very new the javascript... everything I know I literally learned in the last 2 hours. That being said...

So I know that eval is not the greatest thing to use, but I'm trying to write a simple program in which you can input a javascript snippet into a textarea, click an execute button, and have the javascript execute inside another textarea. I'm trying to stay away from jquery for now, because I want to get the really basic idea down before I add another level of complexity, which is why I'm not using id's.... but if jquery is the only way to do this, then I guess I'll have to pony up and learn it in the next 8 hours.

Code as follows (ish):

```
function executeJS ()
{
    var result = eval(game.input.value);
    game.execute.value=result;
}
<head>
    <body>
    <H1>PRogram</H1>
            <form name="game"> 

            <textarea name="execute" rows="5" cols="30" value=""></textarea><br>
            <textarea type="text" name="input" rows="10" cols="30" value=""></textarea>

            <input type = "button" value = "guess" onclick = "executeJS()</input>
            </form>
    </body>
</head>
```

I'm not getting an output in my execute box.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're saying that you're "not using id's because you're trying to stay away from jQuery"? That doesn't make sense. Id's and jQuery have nothing to do with each other (at least not more than names, nodes, classes and all other things)

Comment: I also said I've learned javascript for all of 2 hours. I'm really going off what the people around me are saying.

Comment: Yeah, sorry :) I didn't mean it in a demeaning way. Anyhow, the right with to go about this would be using ids. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"game" isn't a variable. it's a DOM element name.
if you want to get it's object, give it an id let's say `"game"`, and use `document.getElementById('game')`

- Note that your `<head>` surround the `<body>`
- Your javascript code isn't inside `<script></script` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/u29cH/6/).  However, I would reconsider your idea of not using IDs or libraries:

```
function executeJS() {
    var game = document.forms['game'];
    var result = eval(game.input.value);
    game.execute.value = result;
}
```

And be wary of `eval`.